# Stripe.js suddenly failed to load on website, due to 3rd party cookies being blocked?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, stripe-payments

[image]

For our MERN stack application. The warning `Third-pary cookie will be blocked`, and then at the end of the errors, they all have `/set-cookie` at the end? Any recommendations on why our Stripe suddenly stopped loading, and if it's likely related to the warning about Third-party cookies being blocked?

we use `"@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.2.2"` and `"@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.12.1"` in our frontend react package.json, and `"stripe": "^12.18.0"` in our backend node.js package.json.

Comment: Is this something you're able to reproduce on a minimal test site that only loads stripe.js?

Comment: I probably don't have the bandwidth to reproduce this on a prod site loading stripe.js.

Comment: I'm thinking more and more that this is an issue related to the warning about third-party cookies, this warning just appeared for me today after updating my chrome browser. I tested this on a second computer, updating chrome on that laptop, and again the issue only appeared after updating to latest chrome version.

Comment: Looks like it's related to Google Chrome's phase out of all third-party cookies: https://blog.google/products/chrome/privacy-sandbox-tracking-protection/